# jQuery Plugin name spacing and accessing settings parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to create a jQuery Plugin using there name spacing system, so this is a small example of what i have

```
(function($){
var jScrollerMethods = {
    init:function(config){
        this.settings = $.extend({
            'option':'value'
        }, config);
    },
    getOption:function(){
        return this.settings.option;
    }
}

$.fn.jScroller = function(call){
    if ( jScrollerMethods[call] ) {
      return jScrollerMethods[call].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof call === 'object' || ! call ) {
      return jScrollerMethods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  call + ' does not exist on jQuery.jScroller' );
    } 
}

$(".selector").jScroller({'option':'newValue'});
var opt = $(".selector").jScroller("getOption");
```

})(jQuery);

the `opt` variable does not work and it should not work as when declaring functions like that the `this` points to the function E.G into the `init:function(){..` `this` points to the function set to `init` so how do i make it so that the `getOption` function can access the settings but these can't be saved to the window as there could be more than one instance of the jScroller running on differing selectors i just get seem to find or figure it out

Comment: Do you have an element in the DOM called `.selector` when you are running this?

Comment: i would have, this above is not my actual code but an implementation of the problem I'm facing, i'm hoping not to have to save against the elements if your think of using `.attr("jScrollerSettings", JSON.stringify(this.settings));` then using `.attr("jScrollerSettings")` on other methods is there not a cleaner way to do it as that is horrible and some of settings my not for users to change there just a save point

Comment: maybe you should show your actual code; this code is riddled with errors.

Comment: Fixed and i can't as my real code is massive and would just confuse users and it's not finished i'm jsut facing that problem now while im building it

Comment: Ok, I see what you're doing now. Gimme a sec, I'll show you what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a unique options object for each instance, and you need to store it with the instance. jQuery `data()` is great for this. This uses Crockford's `Object.create()` which you may have opinions about.

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
  /* 
     Function: create

     create a new instance of an object using an existing object as its prototype

     Parameters:
        o - the object serving as the new prototype

     Returns:
        a new object
  */         
  Object.create = function (o) {
     function F() {}
     F.prototype = o;
     return new F();
  };
```

}

Then in your init function, add something like this:

```
return this.each(function() {            
    var self = this,
    $this = $(this),
    data = $this.data('jScroll'),
    opts = Object.create(options);

    if (!data) {
        $this.data('jScroll', {
          options: opts, // this is the options object that you'll access later
          element: this // you may not need this
        });
    }
});
```

and your `getOptions` method executes this:

```
var data = this.data('jScroll');
if (data.options[options]) { return data.options[options] };
```

I do the settings merge before I call init:

```
} else if ( typeof call === 'object' || ! call ) {
    if (call) { $.extend(settings, call) } // this expects a settings variable defined with defaults
    return jScrollerMethods.init.apply( this, call );
}
```